# Solve the problem between servlet and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I wrote getRecords() function to get data from MySQL, I tested it in main() and it gives correct result. But when I call it in the Servlet's doGet() function it returns me an empty list. Why?

```
public class EmpDao {
public static List<Emp> getRecords(int start, int total) {
    List<Emp> list = new ArrayList<Emp>();
    try {
        Connection connection = new DBContextMySQL().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from employee limit "+(start-1)+","+total);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Emp e = new Emp(rs.getInt(1),
                    rs.getString(2),
                    rs.getFloat(3));
            list.add(e);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println(exception);;
    }

    return list;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Emp> list = EmpDao.getRecords(1,5);
        for(Emp e : list){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

}

///and class DBContexMySQL

```
public class DBContextMySQL {
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ dbname + "?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8";
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
}

private final String username = "root";
private final String password = "123456789";
private final String dbname = "employee";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Connection con = new DBContextMySQL().getConnection();
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from employee";
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

}

and doGet method

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/ViewServlet", name = "ViewServlet")
public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String spageid = request.getParameter("page");
        int pageid = Integer.parseInt(spageid);
        int total = 5;
        if (pageid == 1) {
        } else {
            pageid = pageid - 1;
            pageid = pageid * total + 1;
        }
        List<Emp> list = EmpDao.getRecords(pageid, total);

        out.print("<h1>Page No: " + spageid + "</h1>");
        out.print("<table border='1' cellpadding='4' width='60%'>");
        out.print("<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th>");
        for (Emp e : list) {
            out.print("<tr><td>" + e.getId() + "</td><td>" + e.getName() + "</td><td>" + e.getSalary() + "</td></tr>");
        }
        out.print("</table>");

        out.print("<a href='ViewServlet?page=1'>1</a> ");
        out.print("<a href='ViewServlet?page=2'>2</a> ");
        out.print("<a href='ViewServlet?page=3'>3</a> ");

        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ thịnh vũ, please insert all the code here, and I would recommend you to check the value of variable pageid and total, before calling the EmpDao.

Comment: Hi @ 
Amrit Malla, i have inserted the full code, and also checked the pageid and total, everything is working fine until i check the list in doGet(). Please help me

Comment: @ thịnh vũ, Can you share the code in github?

Comment: @  Amrit Malla. my link github https://github.com/vuthinh0301/PaginationServlet